# tab bar on iPhone, but not on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, autolayout, size-classes

I'm developing a universal app.
The overall design is to have tab bars on iPhones, but not on iPads.

I've been trying to use size class, but found no luck.

Some example apps are MLB At bat and EBates, they have tab bars on the iPhone version but not on the iPad one.

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To hide tab bar in a specific iPad view(s).  In your `viewdidload` method.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

        self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES; 

    }
```

You could create a custom class of UIViewController and put this method in  if you have many or a mixture of  controllers that require this behaviour. You don't mention the specific behaviour you require

or

In your in your navigation controller (if you're creating one) use `myController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES`. If you're creating one in your AppDelegate for instance it would hide the tabbar  throughout the views that are in the hierarchy of the `navigationController` (any view unless you use another `navigationController` in your app)

```
MyController *myController = [[MyController alloc]init];

// Hide tab bar for all app 
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { 
    myController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES; 
  }

[self.navigationController pushViewController:myController animated:YES];
```

You could always subclass your `navigationController` to achieve the same if you're using interface builder to achieve the same behaviour

You have not  stated what language you're using Objective C or swift.  Tagging your question with the language would be useful.  The auto layout tag is irrelevant as this is nothing to do with autolayout